# How to delete the news widget in windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, widgets

I upgraded to windows 11, and there are the new widgets. But I don't like the news widget that comes by default and want to remove it. Is there any way to do that?

Edit:

The method suggested is not working:
[image: News not showing]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Widgets are in the Task Bar (Much different than Windows 10).

Right click on the Task Bar, and click on Settings.

Turn Widgets OFF

[image: Widgets]

The app is benign if turned off so no need to uninstall.  The related App is Microsoft News and Features in Apps and Features (Start, Settings). Microsoft News and Features App can be uninstalled.

If you wish to Uninstall Microsoft News, you can do that in Apps. Start, Settings, Apps, Apps and Features and then scroll down to Microsoft News.  Three vertical dots beside News, click on that and Uninstall.

Please use care as this may have a side effect on Widgets.

.

You may also need to set Notifications and Focus Assist (depending on how you set up) if you are getting notifications you do not want.

I just have this stuff in the background in Windows 11 and do not see anything.

[image: Remove News]

.

Comment: Hi, what I meant was I want to keep widgets. I want to delete news. I already did what you had suggested but I couldn’t find Microsoft News.

Comment: I added a section on removing News.  Use care as this may have a side effect on Widgets.

Comment: Also, you may need to Repair Windows 11 if News is not in Apps and Features as I showed (two machines here with News in Apps and Features).

Comment: Use the Windows 11 Repair Install. Follow this guide ...  https://www.yourwindowsguide.com/2021/08/repair-install-windows-11-using-an-iso-file.html#.YZOadU7MJd8   ...  It is similar to a Windows 10 Repair.

Comment: Are there any alternatives?

Comment: I do not know of an alternative. You can live with the situation until time permits a Repair.

Answer (score 2):

from PowerShell as administrator run:

```
winget uninstall "windows web experience pack"
```

You can install it again from:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-web-experience-pack/9mssgkg348sp

Answer (score 1):

To remove the News widget from Windows 11:

- Open *Settings > Apps > Apps &features*
- Inside the field "App list", type `microsoft news`
- Once it's displayed, click its three-point menu
- Select "Uninstall"
- Click again "Uninstall" for confirmation
- Close Settings
- Restart Windows.

A demonstration of this method can be found in the YouTube post
[How To Uninstall and Remove Microsoft News Widget In Windows 11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EvBfpEcysg).

Comment: I did that and the widget still shows Headlines

Comment: "Apps & Features" no longer shows here, and I am unable to find where they moved it.   They really don't want you turning off their stupid news feed

Comment: @GorttheRobot: I see, they changed everything again.

Comment: If only it was made easy to add things we want, and remove things we don't want (such as a service leeching resources and bandwidth to serve the news chosen for you), then, why, every Windows user would feel like a Super User! \o/

Answer (score 0):

There is also a reg key and a gpo

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-disable-widgets-in-windows-11-registry-group-policy

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.