# How can I remove news cards in Windows 11 widget panel without remove widgets?

Tags: windows-11

How can I remove news cards in Windows 11 widget panel without remove widgets?

I already try this answer [How to delete the news widget in windows 11?](https://superuser.com/questions/1687419/how-to-delete-the-news-widget-in-windows-11) to do:

1. I don't want to just turn off Widgets panel in Settings app or via Regedit, as I said I want to keep widgets, only I want is just remove news cards.
2. I have already removed Microsoft News by using `Get-AppxPackage "Microsoft.BingNews" | Remove-AppxPackage`
3. I also tried to uninstall Windows Web Experience Pack but Widgets panel would just gone.

One way I know probably solve this problem is trying click hide or reduce from the menu of each news card, but it will be a lots work to do, I already done this way before, but they will just appears again after a moment.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot currently disable news from the widgets, although many
people have asked for it and several feedback requests were filed
with Microsoft.

You may be able to hide certain types of publishers by using the
"Manage" option. You can hide stories from certain publishers,
but there are thousands.

Many users have uninstalled widgets and replaced them by other more
specialized apps for weather and more.

This may change in the future, but for the moment it's unavoidable.

Comment: I just mark all source (as possible) of news to blacklist again in Microsoft Start service. The goal is achieved, but when the widget panel is opened, it will show errror snackbar with "Content fetch failed!" message 
And maybe blacklist will be automatically empty again after a moment...

Comment: Maybe, is it able to find the api that widget panel get the news and block the host?

Comment: That would take some serious hacking.

Comment: I try to block `assets.msn.com` in host file, and it was worked, until, after I reboot my computer and all widgets just gone, widget panel still can open but basic function of widget panel just missing, I cannot even add new widgets.

Comment: After I remove `assets.msn.com` in host file to try to make widgets back, but news cards just come back and I need to hide each of them again... And still some widgets missing and I cannot add them back.

Comment: In every article I saw, the answer was that news can't be blocked if you wish to keep the widgets.

Comment: I fonud Windows Web Experience Pack use webview with `app.js` and `app.css` file, maybe the most simple way is add some css rule into `app.css` to hide there news card, maybe `cs-personalized-feed` I guess

Comment: News can be hidden in build 26010 finally https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2023/12/07/announcing-windows-11-insider-preview-build-26010-canary-channel/